# Is there a way where i can put a left arrow above a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I have two divs inside a div with width 100%. One div has the width 70% and another one has 30%. What I am trying to do is the 30% div to have Left Arrow** when a link is on active.

Here you can see a little bit about my code and also the image where the design is.

```css
.menu a.active:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: -21px;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  background: #FFF;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  border-opacity: 0.3;
  border-left: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  border-bottom: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  /* for Safari */
  background-clip: padding-box;
  /* for IE9+, Firefox 4+, Opera, Chrome */
}

.menu a.active {
  position: relative;
  background: #FFF;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  /* width: 250px; */
  /* height: 250px; */
  /* padding:5px; */
  z-index: 1;
  border-opacity: 0.3;
  /* border: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3); */
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  /* for Safari */
  background-clip: padding-box;
  /* for IE9+, Firefox 4+, Opera, Chrome */
}
```

```html
<div id="featured">
  <!--div with width 70%-->
  <div class="fragments-together ">
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="box  overlay-image-up">
        <span class="top-title">Upcoming events</span>
        <span>
          <img class="slider-homepage" src="./img/slider-home-page.png"/>
        </span>
        <div class="info">
          <div class="info-left">
            <span>17 January 2020</span>
            <h1>European youth gathered in Buzau at the end of the year</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="info-right">
            <button>see more</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box  overlay-image-up">
        <span class="top-title">Upcoming events</span>
        <span>
          <img class="slider-homepage" src="./img/slider-home-page.png"/>
        </span>
        <div class="info">
          <div class="info-left">
            <span>17 January 2020</span>
            <h1>European youth gathered in Buzau at the end of the year</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="info-right">
            <button>see more</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box  overlay-image-up">
        <span class="top-title">Upcoming events</span>
        <span>
          <img class="slider-homepage" src="./img/slider-home-page.png"/>
        </span>
        <div class="info">
          <div class="info-left">
            <span>17 January 2020</span>
            <h1>European youth gathered in Buzau at the end of the year</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="info-right">
            <button>see more</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box  overlay-image-up">
        <span class="top-title">Upcoming events</span>
        <span>
          <img class="slider-homepage" src="./img/slider-home-page.png"/>
        </span>
        <div class="info">
          <div class="info-left">
            <span>17 January 2020</span>
            <h1>European youth gathered in Buzau at the end of the year</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="info-right">
            <button>see more</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay-slider"></div>
  </div>
  <ul class="ui-tabs-nav">
    <div class="menu">
      <a href="#" data-picindex="1">
        <span><img src="./img/cube-icon.png" alt="">21 Feb 2019</span>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod </h2>
      </a>
      <a href="#" data-picindex="2">
        <span><img src="./img/cube-icon.png" alt="">21 Feb 2019</span>
        <h2>European youth gathered in Buzau at the end of the year</h2>
      </a>
      <a href="#" data-picindex="3">
        <span><img src="./img/cube-icon.png" alt="">21 Feb 2019</span>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod </h2>
      </a>
      <a href="#" data-picindex="4">
        <span><img src="./img/cube-icon.png" alt="">21 Feb 2019</span>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod </h2>
      </a>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Is there any way where i can add an arrow to the div? I am using a slider, and this is a slider..

[image]

Thank you for your time!!

Comment: give more z-index to the arrow , more than the menu, try it in inspect element.

Comment: Yes, i tried that many times but didn't work.

Comment: can you share  a link or fiddle, so we can check

Comment: @AhmedSunny yes, here you can check it out: https://jsbin.com/datoxerave/2  and https://jsbin.com/datoxerave/edit?html,css,js .. Maybe you can help he how to do the arrow :)